# Open local Access database and connect to SQL to run Access macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm writing some VBA code in excel to open a local access database and run a macro that is stored within the access database, this part works. The problem that I have is that when I run the access query. It's asking for me to login to the `Microsoft ODBC for Oracle connector` as the local access file connects to a external database. I can write VBA to make a connection to the database however this leaves me unable to run my access macro and makes me run queries local in excel.

```
Sub GetData()

Dim dbConnectStr As String
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim recordCount As Long
dbConnectStr = "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=SERVER;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;"


'con.ConnectionString = dbConnectStr
'con.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
'con.Open dbConnectStr 'ConnectionString

Dim aa As Object
Set aa = CreateObject("Access.Application")
aa.OpenCurrentDatabase ("FILE_PATH\DATABASE.accdb")
    aa.DoCmd.RunMacro "macNAME"
aa.Quit

End Sub
```

I require help to:

1. Run macro in excel.
2. Macro opens local access file.
3. excel Macro runs macro in access (runs multiple queries)
4. Once it runs macro in access, Login to "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle connector".
5. Wait xx minutes
6. Done

Comment: If you are saying that your code runs something that needs to connect to both Access and Oracle data there is no easy way to do this in Excel VBA,  You will need to write code to do whatever this Access code/query currently does.

Comment: @Gareth Thanks I was worried that would be the case, I thought it might have been possible to pass the connection over as I can do both separately. Are you aware of anyway to save the connection details in access so the access macro will be automatically connected?

Comment: There are.  it depends how you have configured things so it would be hard to know without giving full details and there are security implications as it would leave your logon details vulnerable.  Without knowing more the simplest thing (assuming you run this yourself) is to ask the Oracle DBA to give you an account with pass-though authentication.  The other thought is to put all your code (including the code doing your Excel processes into Access.